# ValueError in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm getting a strange error and can't figure out why. I'd appreciate any input. I've been stuck on this for a few days. Here is my code:

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model): 
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=75) 
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=75) 
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position) 
    jurisdiction = models.ForeignKey(Jurisdiction) 
    basepay = models.FloatField()
    ot = models.FloatField()
    benefits = models.FloatField()
    totalpay = models.FloatField()

    class Meta: 
        ordering = ['lastname', 'firstname'] 
    def __unicode__(self): 
        return "%s %s" % (self.firstname, self.lastname) 
    def full_name(self): 
        return "%s, %s" % (self.lastname, self.firstname) 
    def get_absolute_url(self): 
        return "/salaries/employee/%s/" % self.id
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from djangodemo.salaries.models import Employee
from django.views.generic import list_detail

employee_info = {
    "queryset" : Employee.objects.all(),
    "template_name" : "salaries/employee.html",
}

urlpatterns = patterns('',     
    (r'^salaries/employee/$', list_detail.object_list, 'employee_info'),
)
```

employee.html

```
{{ object_list }}
```

When I run python manage.py runserver and look at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/salaries/employee` in my browser, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "F:\django\instantdjango\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 279, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)

  File "F:\django\instantdjango\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 651, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)

  File "F:\django\instantdjango\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)

  File "F:\django\instantdjango\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 73, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)

  File "F:\django\instantdjango\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\middleware\common.py", line 57, in process_request
    _is_valid_path("%s/" % request.path_info)):

  File "F:\django\instantdjango\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\middleware\common.py", line 142, in _is_valid_path
    urlresolvers.resolve(path)

  File "F:\django\instantdjango\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 294, in resolve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)

  File "F:\django\instantdjango\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 218, in resolve
    sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)

  File "F:\django\instantdjango\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 123, in resolve
    kwargs.update(self.default_args)

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',     
    (r'^salaries/employee/$', list_detail.object_list, 'employee_info'),
)
```

The third item in the tuple needs to be a dictionary, not a string. Try removing the single quotes around employee_info:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',     
    (r'^salaries/employee/$', list_detail.object_list, employee_info),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

may be you mean the URL `name`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',     
    (r'^salaries/employee/$', list_detail.object_list, name='employee_info'),
)
```